# Test.stopTest() does not run @futureJob called from an enqueuedJob

Tags: apex, unit-test, future, asynchronous, asyncapexjob

I have a future job that is called from an enqueued job. The code works fine when I run manual tests; however, when my test class, which looks like the code below doesn't finish the future job:

```
Test.startTest();
system.enqueueJob(new EnqueuableClass([InputParameters]));
Test.stopTest();
System.assertEquals(true, futureJobIsComplete());
```

When I remove "@future" from the method and rerun the same test method, the assertion works fine. This problem looks very similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36806/does-test-stoptest-ensure-a-system-schedule-database-batchable-completes-in-a) in nature but they are talking about batch from schedulable and not future from queueable but I would not be surprised if the root cause is the same. Any ideas on what is causing this and how I can resolve it?

UPDATE: All futureJobIsComplete() does is to query the database to assert the records that the futureJob was supposed to update are updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Test.stopTest()` only forces any asynchronous processing which is already enqueued to fire. It does not affect any subsequent asynchronous processing kicked off by those jobs.

```
   |-------------|------------|----------->
startTest    enqueueJob    stopTest
                            job runs synchronously
                            future invoked
                              |------------------->
                             future runs asynchronously
                             since stopTest hasn't been called since invocation
```

If you have a job which kicks off further asynchronous processing, test the `execute` method separately from your `enqueueJob`.

```
@IsTest
static void testJob()
{
    Test.startTest();
        system.enqueueJob(new MyJob());
    Test.stopTest();

    // assert on what you can
}
@IsTest
static void testJobExecute()
{
    Test.startTest();
        new MyJob().execute(/*context*/ null);
        Integer futureCalls = Limits.getFutureCalls();
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(1, futureCalls, 'The future method should be called');
    // assert on future method behavior
}
```